# Include Folder From Other Project While Click-once Publish

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, publishing

I have 3 projects in my solution **MainProject**,  **Library**, and **Configuration**. In the **Configuration** project I have a folder named **Conf** that contains `XML` configuration files when I publish the main project the **Conf** folder and its content is excluded.

How can I include the folder and the contained files while publishing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify that they are content and should be included.  By default, things like XML files are set to a "Build Action" of "None".

In the Solution Explorer window, right-click each file to get the Properties view.  Then choose "Build Action" as "Content" and "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy if newer".  When you build and/or publish, you'll see those files get the appropriate *.deploy extension in the output.

Comment: i  tried to do that but while publish the main project the folder from the other project that has been marked as build action=Content is excluded but while i trying to public the another project that contains the **xml** file the file is include please help me while publishing the main project